# Planning to create a CFT which need 3 roles with managed policy and a inline policy attached to them

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an CFT which has 
1. 3 different roles with Managed policy
2. INline policy which should be added to three roles which are created in CFT.

But i could not do as this is throwing me error saying atleast one resource must be defined.

Please help me in achieving this.

{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {

```
    "EMRDefaultRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "RoleName": "EMR_DefaultRole",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }]
            },
            "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceRole"
            ]
        }
    },
    "EMREC2DefaultRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "RoleName": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }]
            },
            "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role"
            ]
        }
    },
    "EMRAutoScalingDefaultRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "RoleName": "EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": [ "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
                        "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"]
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }]
            },
            "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforAutoScalingRole"
            ]
        }
    },
    "EMRS3Policies": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
        "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "Moodys-IAM-EMR-S3-Access-Policy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Statement": [{
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:HeadBucket",
                            "s3:GetObject"
                        ],
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::mit-", {
                                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                            }, "-emr-files/*"]]
                        }
                    }

                ]
            },
            "Roles": [{
                "Ref": "EMRDefaultRole"},
                {"Ref": "EMREC2DefaultRole"},
                {"Ref": "EMRAutoScalingDefaultRole"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Like i am expecting three Role where an managed policy and inline policy are attached.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `resource` attribute in your role statements.

```
"Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": [ "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
        "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"]
     },
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
 }]
```

This should be (it holds for all of the statements)

```
 "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": [ "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
        "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"]
     },
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Resource": [
         "arn-of-your-resource-or-wildcard"
     ]
 }]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, Bit more confused, from AWS docs:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html.. IAM Role do not have anything called resource as per syntax and in my case i want to EMRS3Policies policy to EMRDefaultRole and EMREC2DefaultRole and EMRAutoScalingDefaultRole roles. If i try EMRDefaultRole  and EMRS3Policies alone in CFT they are working fine. but if i mention 3 role it is failing to add

Comment: @Abhinay It is not role but the policy statement that requires resource attribute, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html